# Where is the least polluted place to live on earth?

Tags: pollution

Where is the least-polluted place on Earth that people are permanently resident and bring up children?

Adding detail per request in comments: I’m asking about all forms of pollution, at the local (town/village/hamlet) level. Anywhere that people live where it’s not so remote or climactically unfriendly that it’s unfeasible to bring up children (eg the North Pole).

Comment: Are you asking about all forms of pollution: air, land & water (ground water, rivers, lakes, water reservoirs, coastal waters), or just one form of pollution? Also are you asking about country, region or city/town? What size of town & how remote? From the link provided by @gansub in his comment, WHO may rate Australia as having the least air pollution but don't disturb some of the river or harbor sediments in Sydney. Factories long ago left a toxic residue in some of the waterways around Sydney. The same applies for other parts of the world. ...

Comment: Don't reside anywhere near Port Pirie, South Australia, the lead smelter there has been contaminating the land for more than a century with lead dust. A similar situation exists for Mount Isa in Queensland, though not as bad as in Port Pirie. Port Augusta in South Australia has an abandoned coal fired power station which has a coal ash dump. When the plant was running the dump was wet & everything was OK. Now the dump is dry & metal laden coal ash is being blown around the region.

Comment: @Fred: I’m asking about all forms of pollution, at the local (town/village/hamlet) level. Anywhere that people live where it’s not so remote or climactically unfriendly that it’s unfeasible to bring up children (eg the North Pole).

Comment: No actual hard evidence but the West Coast of British Columbia, in particular, Vancouver Island has reasonably clean air, and clean water.  There is little in the way of primary manufacturing industries outside of Pulp Production and Sawmills and their influence is limited to certain areas.  The weather typically comes in from over the pacific ocean.  The last two years had some impact from forest fires but compared to the inland areas it could be considered minor and short term.  Cost of living is high but there is work available.

Comment: @gansub I’m just interested in whether there are places to live that are significantly less polluted (in all the various ways) than the norm.